# MySQL inventory query with 3 tables: inventory, pricelistA, pricelistB

Tags: mysql, distinct, inventory

My goal is to print my on-hand inventory without duplicate columns.

Lets say I have an inventory table with parts from 2 different suppliers.  I also have 2 prices list tables, one for each respective supplier A & B.

The inventory table is simple (atomic):

```
item (key), bin, quantity
```

Each price list is simple (atomic):

```
item (key), description, price
```

Is there a simple mysql query that will produce the following using all 3 tables?

```
item   |    description     |     bin     |     quantity     |     price
```

Comment: Can the same item appear in both supplier tables?

Comment: You might do either a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or use MySQL [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) construct.

Comment: Along the same lines of question by @Mureinik is there any reason to duplicate the description field on the different supplier tables?  Why have different tables for different suppliers?  It this were properly normalize, you would probably have tables for item (table with item id and description), item_inventory, supplier (table listing different suppliers), and item_supplier (table mapping item to supplier with price for that item/supplier combination). If you ever have two tables in your DB with the same exact columns, this should be a red flag to you that your schema is not normalized.

Comment: The same item should not appear in both supplier tables, ie unique... but with real-world usage, there usually are a few (and I remove them when I find them)

Comment: I've not used the MySQL IF before, I'll take a look at it when I get the time.

The reason there are two supplier tables is that I download the price lists from each supplier, use awk and sed to clean them up (remove <CR> and other nasty stuff), and build the table with bash scripts that call mysql for creating and inserting into each table.

If I normalize the schema, would that complicate mysql statements?

Thanks for your help